# Waiting for http request in custom validator

Tags: angular, http

I made a custom validator for my template-driven form to check if username already exist in database but since http request are async my function always returns null;

Is there a way I can wait for getUser() function to end and set isValid field to false before returning it?

```
function validateUSERNAMEFactory(userService: UserService) : ValidatorFn {
    return (c: AbstractControl) => {

        var user:User[];
        var isValid = true;

        userService.getUsers().subscribe((data: User[])=>{
            user = data;
            for(let u of user){
                if(u.korIme===c.value) isValid = false;
            }
          });

        if(isValid) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return {
                korIme: {
                    valid: false
                }
            };
      }
    }
}
```

Code from service class:

```
  getUsers(){
    return this.http.get(`${this.url}/home`);
  }
```

My directive class:

```
  export class USERNAMEValidator implements Validator { 
    validator: ValidatorFn;

    constructor(private userService: UserService) {
        this.validator = validateUSERNAMEFactory(this.userService);
      }

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        return this.validator(c);
    }

   }
```

Comment: Consider [implementing a custom async validator](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#implementing-custom-async-validator).

Comment: the code is currently returning a value without waiting for the response from your service call. you should should your conditional to be within the subscribe. as @R.Richards mentioned, async validators are the standard for this scenario. here is another link if you're not familiar with how to link the custom async validator to your form control https://alligator.io/angular/async-validators/